# How do I sort out these columns on tablet/mobile device?

Tags: html, css, mobile, tablet

I am trying to restyle an FAQ page. I need to fix the spacing after categories on mobile/tablet devices. I tried to fix it with padding and width, but didn't work quite well.

```
.faqs_content .faq_content .faq .media-left {
padding: 0 30px;
}
```

Comment: one of your problems is you are setting static widths on your bootstrap columns. You put `col-sm-3 faq_category` then made a style `col-sm-3 faq_category { width: 278px; }`. This is anti-responsive, your column widths should be in %. I would recommend against messing with any bootstrap `container`, `row`, or `col-` paddings, margins or widths. Don't fight the framework!

Comment: What width should i set in %?

Comment: The width of `col-sm-3` is already set in the bootstrap.css file for you (width: 25%), so simply remove `faq_category { width: 278px; }` and that column will be set at 25%.

Comment: I did remove width, still same in mobile/tablet. I don't understand why i get no space between here
http://nkv.name/screenshots/2016-11-10_230624.png

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/baz13y8u/#&togetherjs=G0QdA14xEN

Answer (score 1):

Using padding is not the way for do that. You should use `flex-box` for responsive design, or something like `float`, i recommend you to read this post https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

And if you don't want to use flex-box the easiest way for build a responsive design website using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely want to use percentages if you want to use it to be responsive.